# Is it possible to refer or update memcache/reddis/DB data from spark jobs?

Tags: mongodb, caching, apache-spark, pyspark, memcached

We have some business data in cache/DB. We process tons of log data every day and update our data cache/DB. Some of these updates happen in near real-time and some in batch. We have spark jobs doing lot of transformations. We store the results from spark jobs in text files and later run another sequential job to put them in our cache/DB.

I have considered using connectors(mongoDB-spark connector, redis-spark connector), and bringing the entire data as RDD and do processing on them. But the size of our business data is really huge comparing the log files and daily updates we do. So, dropped it.

**Questions:**

1. Can we do direct update from executors on our cache/DB so that the avoid last step?
2. Any other suggestions or alternate approach for better performance?
3. Do you see any anti-pattern here?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Yes, you can write from Spark directly into a DB or anything else that has a Java/scala connector.

Comment: Agree to what you said, It definitely possible. But I was wondering about the performance of opening and closing connections for every record transformation. Are there any other better ways to share the connections @ executors level? Broadcasting of connections won't help I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your write to the DB is simple, you can write straight to the DB using:

```
myDF.write
    .mode("overwrite") // Choose the mode you want from org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
    .jdbc(url, "my_table", props)
```

if the query is more than just a simple insert (e.g. I had a query with `on duplicate key update` section in my query), you will need to do it yourself.

You can use `mapPartitions()` to distribute the writing between the partitions.

```
myDF.mapPartitions(rows => {
  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, properties)

  rows.foreach(bulk => {
      val statement = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery)
      bulk.foreach(row => {
        statement.setString(1, row.getString(0))
        statement.setInt(2, row.getInt(1))
        ...
        statement.addBatch()
      })

      statement.executeLargeBatch().iterator
    })
  rows
}).count //An action here is required, to trigger the mapPartitions()
```